# Can you get help from Allah through people (e.g. a psychologist)?

Tags: halal-haram, allah, helping

Can you get help from Allah through people?  Is it okay to go see a psychologist or something like that?

Comment: Would you please make your question clear. What you mean by people?

Comment: If you have a medical condition that requires a psychologist, you should definitely seek attention. Remember all brain disorders are real diseases and require medical attention.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But we pay attention that everyone work and service to us/(for you) under power of Allah.

> يٰا أَيُّهَا اَلَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اِتَّقُوا اَللّٰهَ وَ اِبْتَغُوا
>   إِلَيْهِ اَلْوَسِيلَةَ وَ جٰاهِدُوا فِي سَبِيلِهِ لَعَلَّكُمْ
>   تُفْلِحُونَ  ﴿4:35﴾
>
> O, you who believe! Fear from The disobedience of Allāh's Commands
>   and seek the means of getting near to Him; and strive hard in His Way,
>   so that you may receive salvation

For any work we can help from other people. But only we don't allow to believe that those people have independence from Allah. Because that is 'sherk'.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirk_(Islam)

> قُلْ يٰا أَهْلَ اَلْكِتٰابِ تَعٰالَوْا إِلىٰ كَلِمَةٍ سَوٰاءٍ
>   بَيْنَنٰا وَ بَيْنَكُمْ أَلاّٰ نَعْبُدَ إِلاَّ اَللّٰهَ وَ لاٰ
>   نُشْرِكَ بِهِ شَيْئاً وَ لاٰ يَتَّخِذَ بَعْضُنٰا بَعْضاً أَرْبٰاباً
>   مِنْ دُونِ اَللّٰهِ فَإِنْ تَوَلَّوْا فَقُولُوا اِشْهَدُوا بِأَنّٰا
>   مُسْلِمُونَ ﴿3:64﴾

We can use knowledge and help from scientists to solve our problems. But those suggestions and drugs not to be 'haram'.

For example if one scientist suggest us to drink a type of wine we allow to ignore and follow another scientists to found better suggestions. (if a drug marked by things that Allah forbidden that's for us)

> إِنَّمٰا حَرَّمَ عَلَيْكُمُ اَلْمَيْتَةَ وَ اَلدَّمَ وَ لَحْمَ
>   اَلْخِنْزِيرِ وَ مٰا أُهِلَّ بِهِ لِغَيْرِ اَللّٰهِ فَمَنِ اُضْطُرَّ
>   غَيْرَ بٰاغٍ وَ لاٰ عٰادٍ فَلاٰ إِثْمَ عَلَيْهِ إِنَّ اَللّٰهَ غَفُورٌ
>   رَحِيمٌ  ﴿2:173﴾
>
> Allāh has only forbidden to you flesh of Dead animals and blood and
>   flesh Of the swine, and that which is Slaughtered without mentioning
>   Allāh's Name while slaughtering; but If one is forced by necessity 
>   without Willful disobedience or intention of Transgressing the due
>   limits, there is No sin on him. Truly, Allāh is The Merciful
>   Forgiving.

Answer (score 1):

Of course we can get Help from Allah through people.

Allah has said that reach me through waseelah which means... reach Allah through different means...

Allah in the Qur'an says that the Humans are the **HIS REPRESENTATIVES ON EARTH** (khalifa)... hence it is allowed and actually recommended to get help from Allah through the Waseelah of Humans (the representatives of Allah on Earth).